# Remove padding above and below Dropdown Button items

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a Dropdown button to my Flutter web-app, but am getting strange padding above and below my list of menu items when I press the dropdown.

It can be seen in the image below below the "Cabbage" item, and above the "Potato" item.

[image: Dropdown button with strange padding above first and below last items]

I have tried changing the widget parameters, without success. I am applying my own decoration to the button.

Here is my code:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    color: HexColor("F1F9F1"),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: HexColor("1E481E").withOpacity(0.15),
        spreadRadius: 0.5,
        blurRadius: 2.5,
        offset: const Offset(1, 2), 
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 24),
    child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      hint: const Text("Select something"),
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_rounded),
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      isDense: true,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
      underline: Container(
        height: 0,
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :
DropDownButton2
https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2

and add dropdownPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0)

```
 String title = "Service";
  String dropdownValue = "Potato";
  List<String> list = ["Potato", "Onion", "Cabbage"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
       ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          color: HexColor("F1F9F1"),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: HexColor("1E481E").withOpacity(0.15),
              spreadRadius: 0.5,
              blurRadius: 2.5,
              offset: const Offset(1, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 24),
          child: DropdownButton2<String>(
            dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
            ),
            dropdownPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            value: dropdownValue,
            hint: const Text("Select something"),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_rounded),
            isDense: true,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
            underline: Container(
              height: 0,
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = value!;
              });
            },
            items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```